# Nextbook 8 Android Jellybean debug android sdk

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I'm trying to connect a nextbook 8 android tablet to Android Studio for debugging on my Macbook Pro via USB. I've done this successfully with a Samsung Galaxy S3 and S5, but the USB choices are different on the nextbook 8. Instead of having MTP and PTP, it only asks if I want to "Turn on USB storage". Its as if the firmware doesn't support PTP.

Does anyone know if there is a way around this? The Android ADB (Android Device Bridge) seems to only want to work on a Mac with the PTP protocol (Camera USB mode).

Is the PTP protocol an Android thing? Or is it more of a manufacture firmware item?

Comment: PTP isn't an Android thing, but your problem is different. ADB doesn't run over PTP or MTP protocol, but is a separate protocol altogether. For ADB to work, the device has to have its developer options enabled -- try enabling that.

Comment: @Scott - Enabling the developer options was the first thing I did, the only difference I could find between the other devices and the nextbook was the lack of PTP vs. MTP options.

Comment: I'm getting a galaxy tab3 (jellybean) this afternoon and will try it. That might help determine if its a jellybean thing or firmware issue. I'll post the results when I have them.

Comment: Found that the Galaxy Tab 3 (jellybean) worked fine with Android Studio. So perhaps its a problem with the nextbook itself not supporting that prototcol?